# groovy execute with parameters containing spaces

Tags: groovy

How do I provide arguments containing spaces to the execute method of strings in groovy? Just adding spaces like one would in a shell does not help:

```
println 'ls "/tmp/folder with spaces"'.execute().text
```

This would give three broken arguments to the ls call.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The trick was to use a list:

```
println(['ls', '/tmp/folder with spaces'].execute().text)
```

Comment: In case the command is dynamically generated or asked to the user this solution is not working. Surely cannot be so difficult parsing keeping in count the quotes...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry man, none of the tricks above worked for me. 
This piece of horrible code is the only thing that went thru:

```
    def command = 'bash ~my_app/bin/job-runner.sh -n " MyJob today_date=20130202 " ' 
    File file = new File("hello.sh")
    file.delete()       
    file << ("#!/bin/bash\n")
    file << (command)
    def proc = "bash hello.sh".execute()                 // Call *execute* on the file
```

Answer (score 1):

One weird trick for people who need regular quotes processing, pipes etc: use `bash -c`

```
['bash','-c',
'''
docker container ls --format="{{.ID}}" | xargs -n1 docker container inspect --format='{{.ID}} {{.State.StartedAt}}' | sort -k2,1
'''].execute().text
```

Comment: simply said: `["bash","-c","your command with spaces and quotes"].execute().text`

Answer (score -2):

Using a List feels a bit clunky to me.

This would do the job:

```
def exec(act) { 
 def cmd = []
 act.split('"').each { 
   if (it.trim() != "") { cmd += it.trim(); }
 }
 return cmd.execute().text
}

println exec('ls "/tmp/folder with spaces"')
```

More complex example:

```
println runme('mysql "-uroot" "--execute=CREATE DATABASE TESTDB; USE TESTDB; \\. test.sql"');
```

The only downside is the need to put quotes around all your args, I can live with that!

Answer (score -4):

did you tried escaping spaces?

```
println 'ls /tmp/folder\ with\ spaces'.execute().text
```