# Groovy: strings with embedded quotes don't execute as expected

Tags: groovy

This is weird: using groovy strings to hold some command lines for execution, I find that *sometimes* if there are quote characters inside the string, the execution simply silently fails.

WTF? (Updated, see below.)

Here's my test program:

```
print " 1: " ; "grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf".execute().text.eachLine {println it }          ; println ""
print " 2: " ; "grep 'nameserver' /etc/resolv.conf".execute().text.eachLine {println it }        ; println ""
print " 3: " ; """grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf""".execute().text.eachLine {println it }      ; println ""
print " 4: " ; """grep "nameserver" /etc/resolv.conf""".execute().text.eachLine {println it }    ; println ""
print " 5: " ; """grep 'nameserver' /etc/resolv.conf""".execute().text.eachLine {println it }    ; println ""
print " 6: " ; "awk /nameserver/ /etc/resolv.conf".execute().text.eachLine{ println it }         ; println ""
print " 7: " ; "awk '/nameserver/' /etc/resolv.conf".execute().text.eachLine{ println it }       ; println ""
print " 8: " ; """awk "/nameserver/" /etc/resolv.conf""".execute().text.eachLine{ println it }   ; println ""
print " 9: " ; """awk '/nameserver/' /etc/resolv.conf""".execute().text.eachLine{ println it }   ; println ""
print "10: " ; """awk "/nameserver/{print \$2}" /etc/resolv.conf""".execute().text.eachLine{ println it }   ; println ""
return
```

Here's the results:

```
$ groovy weird.groovy 
 1: nameserver 10.3.0.101
nameserver 10.4.1.237
nameserver 10.2.1.34

 2: 
 3: nameserver 10.3.0.101
nameserver 10.4.1.237
nameserver 10.2.1.34

 4: 
 5: 
 6: nameserver 10.3.0.101
nameserver 10.4.1.237
nameserver 10.2.1.34

 7: 
 8: nameserver 10.3.0.101
nameserver 10.4.1.237
nameserver 10.2.1.34
domain lnx.copansys.com
search lnx.copansys.com tst.copansys.com copansys.com

 9: 
10:
```

***Update***

Here's another example:

```
"bash -c echo Hello".execute().text.eachLine{ println it }
"bash -c echo 'Hello'".execute().text.eachLine{ println it }
"bash -c echo \'Hello\'".execute().text.eachLine{ println it }
```

Results:

```
groovy> "bash -c echo Hello".execute().text.eachLine{ println it } 
groovy> "bash -c echo 'Hello'".execute().text.eachLine{ println it } 
groovy> "bash -c echo \'Hello\'".execute().text.eachLine{ println it } 

'Hello!'
```

Observe that embedding a backslash-quoted ' doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you execute commands with `String.execute()`, they don't get parsed by a command shell.  The quotes are passed through to the actual commands executed; in this case, grep and awk.

This is illustrated by replacing grep and awk with echo:

```
print " 1: " ; "echo something".execute().text.eachLine {println it }          ; println ""
print " 2: " ; "echo 'something'".execute().text.eachLine {println it }        ; println ""
print " 3: " ; """echo something""".execute().text.eachLine {println it }      ; println ""
print " 4: " ; """echo "something" """.execute().text.eachLine {println it }   ; println ""
print " 5: " ; """echo 'something'""".execute().text.eachLine {println it }    ; println ""
```

Which results in:

```
 1: something

 2: 'something'

 3: something

 4: "something"

 5: 'something'
```

A simple workaround is to build the command line as a list of strings:

```
["awk", 'BEGIN { print "hello" }'].execute().text
```

If you need finer control over the how the command is parsed, take a look at [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), the Java class `String.execute()` is built around.

Comment: Related, executing strings containing spaces -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786160/groovy-execute-with-parameters-containing-spaces

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings
It seems that the python style quoting ie `"'"` (`'`) and `"""""""` (`"`) you expect doesn't exist in groovy so `'` or `"` in strings literals must be written as `\'` and `\"`

Comment: Thanks, but backslash quoting doesn't seem to help, see the updated example.