# Getting the build status in post-build script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to have a post-build hook or similar, so that I can have the same output as e. g. the IRC plugin, but give that to a script.
I was able to get all the info, except for the actual build status. This just doesn't work, neither as a "Post-build script", "Post-build task", "Parameterized Trigger" aso.

It is possible with some very ugly workarounds, but I wanted to ask, in case someone has a nicer option ... short of writing my own plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Groovy script in post-build step via [Groovy Post-Build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin). You can then access Jenkins internals via [Jenkins Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/). The plugin provides the script with variable *manager* that can be used to access important parts of the API (see *Usage* section in the plugin documentation).

For example, here's how you can execute a simple external Python script on Windows and output its result (as well as the build result) to build console:

```
def command =  """cmd /c python -c "for i in range(1,5): print i" """
manager.listener.logger.println command.execute().text

def result = manager.build.result
manager.listener.logger.println "And the result is: ${result}"
```

Comment: Thank you, that sounds very good. Is it possible to call an external tool, like a script, from there?

Comment: That seems to work, yet the output of the command is not printed.

Comment: Forgot to mention: `cmd /c` applies on windows. On Unix-like systems I think you need to omit it. What about the printout for build result?

Comment: The build result is fine, but the command doesn't seem to get executed. I figured the windows cmd ...
The problem seems to lie with the quoting of the command. When I leave out the quotes, it works, but I need quotes for the command that I actually want to send

Comment: Unfortunately I can't debug remotely :) Search for tips on running external commands from Groovy. Make sure that there is a space before the last three quotes. Also, check Jenkins Log: `http://<jenkins-server>/log/all` for clues. The point is that you can do it (it works for me), so it's just a matter of finding the right incantation.

Comment: is there a way to do something similar with bash script? I mean get a build status.

Comment: This script did not print python output on Linux even after I removed 'cmd /c'

Comment: If there is an error in a shell command, nothing gets printed. To print that, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands

Answer (score 9):

It works as mentioned with the Groovy Post-Build Plugin, yet without any extra quoting within the string that gets executed. So I had to put the actual functionality into a shell script, that does a call to curl, which in turn needs quoting for the POST parameters aso.

```
def result = manager.build.result
def build_number = manager.build.number
def env = manager.build.getEnvironment(manager.listener)
def build_url = env['BUILD_URL']
def build_branch = env['SVN_BRANCH']
def short_branch = ( build_branch =~ /branches\//).replaceFirst("")
def host = env['NODE_NAME']
def svn_rev = env['SVN_REVISION']
def job_name = manager.build.project.getName()


"/usr/local/bin/skypeStagingNotify.sh Deployed ${short_branch} on ${host} - ${result} - ${build_url}".execute()
```

Comment: If there is an error in a shell command, nothing gets printed. To print that, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands

Comment: Also, to execute string containing quotes/spaces in Groovy, it is better to use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/788401/1000551

Answer (score 5):

For this I really like the [Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin.  It's very flexible, and you can choose which actions to take based on build failure or success.  For instance, here's a case where I use conditional build step to send a notification on build failure:

[image]

You can also use conditional build step to set an environment variable or write to a log file that you use in subsequent "execute shell" steps.  So for instance, you might create a build with three steps: one step to compile code/run tests, another to set a `STATUS="failed"` environment variable, and then a third step which sends an email like `The build finished with a status: ${STATUS}`

Answer (score 5):

Really easy solution, maybe not to elegant, but it works!

1: Catch all the build result you want to catch (in this case SUCCESS).

2: Inject an env variable valued with the job status

[image: Step 1]

3: Do the Same for any kind of other status (in this case I catch from abort to unstable)

[image]

4: After you'll be able to use the value for whatever you wanna do.. in this case I'm passing it to an ANT script! (Or you can directly load it from ANT as Environment variable...)

[image]

Hope it can help!

Answer (score 4):

### Groovy script solution:-

Here I am using [groovy script plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) to take the build status and setting it to the environmental variable, so the environmental variable can be used in post-build scripts using [post-build task plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task).

Groovy script:-

```
import hudson.EnvVars
import hudson.model.Environment

def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def result = manager.build.result.toString()  
def vars = [BUILD_STATUS: result]

build.environments.add(0, Environment.create(new EnvVars(vars)))
```

Postscript:-

```
echo BUILD_STATUS="${BUILD_STATUS}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Post Build Task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) plugin...

It lets you specify conditions based on the log output...

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution (please don't laugh)

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUS='Not set'
if [ ! -z $UPSTREAM_BUILD_DIR ];then
  ISFAIL=$(ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$UPSTREAM_BUILD_DIR/builds | grep "lastFailedBuild\|lastUnsuccessfulBuild" | grep $UPSTREAM_BUILD_NR)
  ISSUCCESS=$(ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$UPSTREAM_BUILD_DIR/builds | grep "lastSuccessfulBuild\|lastStableBuild" | grep $UPSTREAM_BUILD_NR)
  if [ ! -z "$ISFAIL" ];then
     echo $ISFAIL
     STATUS='FAIL'
  elif [ ! -z "$ISSUCCESS" ]
  then
     STATUS='SUCCESS'
  fi
fi
echo $STATUS
```

where

$UPSTREAM_BUILD_DIR=$JOB_NAME

$UPSTREAM_BUILD_NR=$BUILD_NUMBER

passed from upstream build

Of course "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/" depends of your jenkins installation