# Execute shell script with options and parameters

Tags: groovy

I'm using Jenkins to launch a script on a linux machine.

When I **run** this **manually** on the server, it **works**:

`/bin/bash -c '/some/script MyProduct SomeBranch'`

When I **run** this with **groovy**, it **doesn't work**.

I get the same error as if I didn't pass the "-c" option, so somehow the **"-c" isn't working**.

Here is my code:

```
branchName = "SomeBranch"
configName = "release"
println "Building for branch "+branchName+" and configuration "+configName

def chkbranch = { String product, String branch -> mkcmd( product, branch ) } 
private def mkcmd ( String product, String branch ) {
  // Build the command string to run
      def cmd = "/bin/bash -c '/some/script "+product+" "+branch+"'"
      def sout = new StringBuffer()
      def serr = new StringBuffer()
  // Run the command
      println "running "+cmd
      def proc = cmd.execute()
      proc.consumeProcessOutput ( sout, serr )
      proc.waitForProcessOutput ()
      println "out> $sout"
      println "err> $serr"
      return sout
}

chkbranch ( "MyProduct", branchName )
```

***Is this the correct way*** to build the command in Groovy?:

```
def cmd = "/bin/bash -c '/some/script "+product+" "+branch+"'"
cmd.execute()
```

Thanks!

Question similar to / helpful resources that I tried:

- [groovy execute with parameters containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786160/groovy-execute-with-parameters-containing-spaces)
- [Groovy executing shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159148/groovy-executing-shell-commands)
- http://www.joergm.com/2010/09/executing-shell-commands-in-groovy/
- https://fbflex.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/replacing-the-groovy-execute-method-with-one-that-prints-output-while-the-process-is-running/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to run the command in the following way:

```
def cmd = ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/some/script", product, branch]
```

You may also try:

```
def cmd = ["/some/script", product, branch]
```

if `/some/script` is executable - BTW is it placed under root (`/`)?

Comment: This worked! Now it's saying "permission denied" for accessing a file within the script, but it's running the script this time! Yes the script is in root, is there anything special I need to worry about for that?

Comment: Rather not. I thought about permissions :)

Comment: it must be `["/bin/bash", "-c", "/some/script $product $branch"]...` - the shell command to run is the sole paramenter after `-c`.  and take double care, what product and branch are.  if product is `<backtick>rm -rf /<backtick>` it will run