# Groovy execute command with quotes

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Looking for a way how to run the simple command in groovy (using in jenkins) with quotes inside.

My code is:

`"grep 'text ' /tmp/test.txt".execute()`

I want to grep all lines with text (and space after it).

But as a result I'm always getting grep of "text" only (without the space). Actually groovy for some reason drops my quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [groovy execute with parameters containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786160/groovy-execute-with-parameters-containing-spaces)

Answer (score 2):

Groovy doesn't handle quotes well. Instead you can use the array form:

```
['grep', 'text ', '/tmp/test.txt'].execute().text
```

Comment: You saved my day, thanks!

Also, `print [...].exectute().text` doesn't work. I needed to define a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def res = ['grep', 'text ', 'test.txt'].execute( null, new File( '/tmp/' ) ).text
```

Comment: your example is equivalent to `grep text test.txt` and i need it to be `grep 'text' test.txt`