# Groovy execute complicated shell command

Tags: groovy

I would like to execute a shell command within a Groovy script where part of the script is variable of a filename which may contain spaces.

According to [groovy execute with parameters containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786160/groovy-execute-with-parameters-containing-spaces) I may use an array for this:

```
def filename = '/tmp/folder with spaces'

// does not work
'ls "' + filename + '"'.execute()

// works
['ls', filename].execute()
```

But I can't figure out how to reformat the following command using an array where "filename" is a groovy variable containing a filename with or without spaces:

```
mdfind "$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print RawQuery' filename)"
```

This does not work:

```
// not working
["mdfind", "\$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print RawQuery' " + filename + ")"].execute()
["mdfind", "\$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print RawQuery' ", filename, ")"].execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

unless knowing what the raw output of `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` might be, it is difficult to tell how the brackets have to be placed in order to provide syntactical sense.

```
println([
    "mdfind",
    "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy",
    "-c 'Print RawQuery'",
    "${filename}"
].execute().text)
```

See the Groovy documentation on [Process Management](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#process-management) - breaking the statement down into two statements might provide some clue, why it doesn't work as expected - while one still can formulate it into a single-line statement, once both parts do return the desired results. one can also `.waitFor()` process termination, before outputting the captured text; also the `|` operator is available there, just not within the `[]` bracketed command/parameter arrays... because I have the impression, that it most likely might be intended to look about like this:

```
def p = "mdfind".execute() | [
    "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy",
    "-c 'Print RawQuery'",
    "${filename}"
].execute()
p.waitFor()
println p.text
```

I'd consider the most simple formulation: `["mdfind", "-name ${filename}"].execute()`

Answer (score 0):

I always run complicated shell commands using split().

Example:

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def shellCommand="" //your shell command here
Process proc = shellCommand.split().execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(100000L)
```