# Curl command in a Groovy-script fails to execute (in Linux)

Tags: curl, groovy, asana

I try to implement a curl command in a groovy script.
The goal off my command is to create a task in Asana.

Is it possible that groovy changes the command at runtime? (is it possible that groovy has some problems with the data-urlencode parameter)
Has this something to do with the version of curl? (version 7.64.0)
(works perfectly when I run it seperatly)

The command works perfectly in a command prompt but fails when I try to run it  in a groovy-script.

```
1 def opsAlert = opsgenie.getAlert(alertId: "${alert.alertId}");
2 //logger.warn("${opsAlert}"); //DEBUG
3 if(opsAlert.isEmpty()){
4 throw new Exception("Failed to get the alert details, opsAlert is null!");
5 }
6
7 if(opsAlert.source.equals("abc@abc.com")){
8 def projects = "<projectid>";
9 def name = opsAlert.details.sensorId;
10 def notes = opsAlert.message;
11 def authorizationToken = "Bearer <mytoken>";
12
13 def command = "curl https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks ";
14 command += "-H \"Authorization: ${authorizationToken}\" ";
15 command += "--data-urlencode \"projects=${projects}\" ";
16 command += "--data-urlencode \"notes=${notes}\" ";
17 command += "--data-urlencode \"name=${name}\"";
18 logger.warn("${command}"); //DEBUG
19
20 def commandResult = "${command}".execute();
21 commandResult.waitFor();
22 logger.warn("${commandResult}");
23
24 //def output1 = commandResult.text;
25 def output2 = commandResult.err.text;     
26 //logger.warn("${output1}"); //DEBUG
27 logger.warn("${output2}"); //DEBUG
28 return;
29 } else {
30 throw new Exception("S(s)ource was not abc!")
31 }
```

This is the command that I try to run: (I also tried the -v option but that doesn't produced useful output)

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer " https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks --data-urlencode "projects=projectId" --data-urlencode "notes=message" --data-urlencode "name=1008"

And this produces the following output
curl: option -: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Can anyone help me with my groovy-script? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [groovy execute with parameters containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786160/groovy-execute-with-parameters-containing-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to prepend the command with the shell, i.e. `def command="/bin/bash curl https..."`

Comment: that gives me the error: /usr/bin/curl: /usr/bin/curl: cannot execute binary file               Do I need to change the path?

Comment: sorry for the delay. Well, `/bin/bash` is the path in my machine

Comment: And if the linux (Ubuntu) is actually a docker container, how can I find the path of my shell?