How to make a curl request from a Groovy file
I am migrating from Jenkins to GitHub Actions. I plan to reuse the script from my Jenkins.
Config-Apps-Products executes script.groovy to perform the necessary configurations using series of cURL commands.
Config-Apps-Products:
name: Name

on:
workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
build:
runs-on: [abc]
steps:
- name: Checkout repository
uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: List files (Start)
run: |
ls
- name: Set up JDK 11
uses: actions/setup-java@v3
with:
java-version: '11'
distribution: 'adopt'
- name: Install Groovy
run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y groovy
- name: Run Groovy script
env:
SECRET_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.ADMINUSER }}
run: groovy Script.groovy
Script.groovy:
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
env = "env"

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

println "*** Before Read ***"

// Reading JSON from file
def jsonFile = new File('AppsProductsConfig.json')
def configs = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonFile.text)

println "configs = $configs"
println "*** After Read ***"

def totalBundles = configs.bundles.size()
println "Total Array Size = $totalBundles"

// Initialization of arrays
def productName = new Object[totalBundles]
def developer = new Object[totalBundles]
def firstName = new Object[totalBundles]
def lastName = new Object[totalBundles]
def userName = new Object[totalBundles]
def approvalType = new Object[totalBundles]
def productAttributeName = new Object[totalBundles]
def productAttributeValue = new Object[totalBundles]
def displayName = new Object[totalBundles]
def environments = new Object[totalBundles]
def proxies = new Object[totalBundles][]
def appName = new Object[totalBundles]
def appAttributeName = new Object[totalBundles]
def appAttributeValue = new Object[totalBundles]
def host = "example.com"
def ADMINUSER = System.getenv("SECRET_API_KEY")

println "*** After Initialisation Read ***"

// Extract and Store Values
println "**** Read Variables ***"
for (int i = 0; i < totalBundles; i++) {
    def bundle = configs.bundles[i]

    // Products
    productName[i] = bundle.product.name
    approvalType[i] = "auto"
    productAttributeName[i] = bundle.product.attributes[0].name
    productAttributeValue[i] = bundle.product.attributes[0].value
    displayName[i] = bundle.product.name
    environments[i] = env
    proxies[i] = bundle.product.proxies.collect { it.replaceAll(/["']/, '') } // Removing quotes from proxies

    // Developer
    developer[i] = bundle.app.developer
    firstName[i] = developer[i].takeWhile { it != '.' }
    def start = developer[i].indexOf(".") + 1
    def end = developer[i].indexOf("@")
    lastName[i] = developer[i].substring(start, end).replaceAll(/[^a-zA-Z]/, "")
    userName[i] = developer[i].takeWhile { it != '@' }

    // Apps
    appName[i] = bundle.app.name
    appAttributeName[i] = bundle.app.attributes[0].name
    appAttributeValue[i] = bundle.app.attributes[0].value

    println "*** Print Apps & Products ***"
    println "Product Name = ${productName[i]}"
    println "App Name = ${appName[i]}"
    println "Approval Type = ${approvalType[i]}"
    println "Product Attributes Name = ${productAttributeName[i]}"
    println "Product Attributes Value = ${productAttributeValue[i]}"
    println "Display Name = ${displayName[i]}"
    println "Environments = ${environments[i]}"
    println "Proxies = ${proxies[i]}"
    println "Developer = ${developer[i]}"
    println "App Attributes Name = ${appAttributeName[i]}"
    println "App Attributes Value = ${appAttributeValue[i]}"
}

for (int i = 0; i < totalBundles; i++) {
    def productBodyMap = [
        approvalType: approvalType[i],
        attributes: [[name: productAttributeName[i], value: productAttributeValue[i]]],
        displayName: displayName[i],
        environments: [environments[i]],
        name: productName[i],
        proxies: proxies[i]
    ]
    def productBody = JsonOutput.toJson(productBodyMap)
    println "Product Body = $productBody"

    def developerBodyMap = [
        email: developer[i],
        firstName: firstName[i],
        lastName: lastName[i],
        userName: userName[i]
    ]
    def developerBody = JsonOutput.toJson(developerBodyMap)
    println "Developer Body = $developerBody"

    def appBodyMap = [
        name: appName[i],
        apiProducts: [productName[i]],
        attributes: [[name: appAttributeName[i], value: appAttributeValue[i]]],
        keyExpiresIn: "100"
    ]
    def appBody = JsonOutput.toJson(appBodyMap)
    println "App Body = $appBody"

    // Products
    def createProductResponse = ["bash", "-c", "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $ADMINUSER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$productBody' --request POST https://${host}/v1/organizations/ORG/apiproducts"].execute().text
    println "*** createProductResponse = $createProductResponse ***"

    if (createProductResponse.contains('201')) {
        println "*** Product ${productName[i]} created successfully ***"
    } else if (createProductResponse.contains('409')) {
        def updateProductResponse = ["bash", "-c", "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $ADMINUSER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$productBody' --request PUT https://${host}/v1/organizations/ORG/apiproducts/${productName[i]}"].execute().text
        println "$updateProductResponse"
        if (updateProductResponse.contains('200')) {
            println "*** Product ${productName[i]} updated successfully ***"
        } else {
            error "Failed to update ${productName[i]} with $updateProductResponse"
        }
    } else {
        error "Failed to create ${productName[i]} with $createProductResponse"
    }

    // Developers
    def createDeveloperResponse = ["bash", "-c", "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $ADMINUSER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$developerBody' --request POST https://${host}/v1/organizations/ORG/developers"].execute().text
    println "$createDeveloperResponse"

    if (createDeveloperResponse.contains('201')) {
        println "*** Developer ${developer[i]} created successfully ***"
    } else if (createDeveloperResponse.contains('409')) {
        println "*** Developer already exists: $createDeveloperResponse ***"
    } else {
        error "Failed to create ${developer[i]} with $createDeveloperResponse"
    }

    // Apps
    def createAppResponse = ["bash", "-c", "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $ADMINUSER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$appBody' --request POST https://${host}/v1/organizations/ORG/developers/${developer[i]}/apps"].execute().text
    println "$createAppResponse"

    if (createAppResponse.contains('201')) {
        println "*** App ${appName[i]} created successfully ***"
    } else if (createAppResponse.contains('409')) {
        def updateAppBodyMap = [
            attributes: [[name: appAttributeName[i], value: appAttributeValue[i]]]
        ]
        def updateAppBody = JsonOutput.toJson(updateAppBodyMap)
        println "Updated App Body = $updateAppBody"

        def updateAppResponse = ["bash", "-c", "curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $ADMINUSER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$updateAppBody' --request PUT https://${host}/v1/organizations/ORG/developers/${developer[i]}/apps/${appName[i]}"].execute().text
        println "$updateAppResponse"
        if (updateAppResponse.contains('200')) {
            println "*** App ${appName[i]} updated successfully ***"
        } else {
            error "Failed to update ${appName[i]} with $updateAppResponse"
        }
    } else {
        error "Failed to create ${appName[i]} with $createAppResponse"
    }
}

I am struggling to make a `curl request` from my `script.groovy` file.

I am making use of .execute() function for my curl which returns:
 *** createProductResponse = Process[pid=2637, exitValue="not exited"] ***
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.ProcessImpl.contains() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [201]
Possible solutions: toString(), toString(), toString(), notify()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.ProcessImpl.contains() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [201]
Possible solutions: toString(), toString(), toString(), notify()
    at script.run(script.groovy:111)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Where exactly do I have an issue?
createProductResponse = $createProductResponse does not result in the expected value.
// Products
    def createProductResponse = ("curl -k -s -w '\\n%{response_code}' --header 'Authorization:Basic $USER' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '$productBody' --request POST https://${host}/v1/organizations/org/apiproducts").execute()
    println "*** createProductResponse = $createProductResponse ***"

    if (createProductResponse.contains('201')) {
        println "*** Product ${productName[i]} created successfully ***"

JSON
{
"bundles":
[
{
"product":{
"name" : "Name",
"proxies" : ["abc","xyz"],
"attributes" : [{"name":"Attribute","value":"value1"}]
},
"app":{
"name":"Name",
"attributes": [{"name": "Attribute","value": "value1"}],
"developer": "raj@example.com"
}
}
]
}

Have you thought about  using URI, HttpClient, HttpRequest, CompletableFuture, TimeUnit classes from the Java APIs instead? I can post a Java solution if it helps you that you can adapt.

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.

Where is sh from? Is this the old code from jenkins?

@JGFMK, as I'm in middle of migration, I prefer not to modify my code by incorporating JAVA. Thanks for asking! :)

@cfrick, I have removed the image. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. :)
Regarding the sh, I had copied the wrong snippet. Please see the updated request in the question.

For starters: never ever use "string".execute() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786160/groovy-execute-with-parameters-containing-spaces - I dare not to dupe-vote, but I bet this is a big part of the problem.

i don't see contains() in your code. it must be something out of this code snippet.

waitForProcessOutput is void. assigning result into createProductResponse makes no sense.  https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.html#waitForProcessOutput(java.lang.Process,java.lang.Appendable,java.lang.Appendable)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Ltf4ZKQ_tjV6sCRDiINYOkZ7Y_7bY3n/view?usp=drive_link - this was a sample in case anyone else was interested.. Not going to give as an answer since it's a different approach to the question posed.

Thank you, @cfrick!
['bash','-c',
'''
docker container ls --format="{{.ID}}" | xargs -n1 docker container inspect --format='{{.ID}} {{.State.StartedAt}}' | sort -k2,1
'''].execute().text - Worked.
